# How to calculate mean average rank (MAR)?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out how mean average rank [(MAR)](https://openreview.net/forum?id=HyePrhR5KX) in graph modelling is calculated. Could someone look through my example and tell me if I'm correct?

Say we have two graphs that look like this:

```
1-2, 3-4
1, 2, 3-4
```

In graph 1, and there are two edges (between nodes 1 and 2 and between nodes 3 and 4).

In graph 2, there is only one edge (between nodes 3 and 4).

**For graph 1:**

To compute the average rank for graph 1 (**for edge 1-2**):

1) We compute the probability that node 1 would connect with nodes 2, 3 and 4, according to our model. Suppose this gives us `[0.09, 0.90, 0.01]`.

2) The rank of node 2 (the ground truth connection) would be 2 here, because it is the connection with the second highest probability.

Now **for edge 3-4** in graph 1:

1) We compute the probability that node 3 would connect with nodes 1, 2 and 4, according to our model. Suppose this gives us `[0.21, 0.04, 0.75]`.

3) The rank of node 4 (the ground truth) is 1.

**So the average rank for the first graph is (2+1)/2 = 1.5**

**For graph 2:**

1) We replace node 4 with nodes 1 and 2.

2) We compute the probability that node 3 connects with nodes 1, 2, or 4. Say that gives us `[0.05, 0.80, 0.15]`.

3) The ground truth is node 4, which had probability 0.15, which has rank 2 (is the second highest probability).

**So the average rank for the second graph is 2/1 = 2.**

**The mean average rank (MAR) would be: (1.5 + 2)/2 = 1.75.**

Is this correct?

Comment: could you tell us where do you get this name from: Mean average rank (MAR) ?

Comment: Yes, it's from this paper: https://openreview.net/forum?id=HyePrhR5KX

Comment: Can you quote the definition? The paper is rather long and ctrl+f didn't help.

Comment: That's the problem: the definition is not provided. I'm trying to work backwards to figure out what the definition is.

Comment: where do you have this name from? Which topic of mathematics this name belongs to? Google is empty if you search after MAR.

Comment: I know, that's part of the problem. Mean Average Ranking (MAR) is a metric for assessing the quality of a model for link prediction in graphs. There's no Google information on it, there are only papers.

Comment: I think, What @StatsSorceress described in the problem is correct according to my logical thinking...

Answer (score 0):

Mean Average Rank is Mean of the Average ranks calculated. See Point 3. Results in https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/7/1031/2571354 
IMHO your understanding is correct. You can also go through https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04441.pdf for Mean reciprocal rank (MRR).
To be sure you can mail the first author on the email id he has provided.